# Reqular Expression Needed To Check For & Remove Special Characters & White Spaces

Tags: c#, regex, membershipuser

I am in need of a regular expression to check for and remove special characters from a `MembershipUser` `userName`.

When I first set the site in beta I did not take into consideration that special characters are not a good way to go for user names, "in my application."

I've got a template piece of code below that is not written correctly but gives the person that is willing to help a head start.

**--I need to remove all special characters and white spaces from user names, update the user name as well.**

When I say special characters I am talking about ~,`,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),+,=,' ',;,:,,{,}. I need for the current users usernames to be checked to see if they have any of these types of special characters and remove them from that specific user username and replacing any special characters with '_' or '-'.

I need to check and make sure that any existing user names only contain letters and numbers, and the user names must not start with a number and must start with an upper or lowercase letter.

```
MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
List<MembershipUser> userToEmail= new List<MembershipUser>();

foreach (MembershipUser user in users) {
    if (user.UserName./*Some type of reg expression here to check for special characters and white spaces*/) {
        user.UserName = user.UserName /*some reg expression to remove special characers and white spaces*/
        Membership.UpdateUser(user);
        userToEmail.Add(user);
    }
}

void EmailUser(List<MembershipUser> userToEmail){}
```

--I am currently using the code below to make sure that only letter and numbers are used in user names when the user account is first created.

As of right now I am needing to do a `user.Replace(regexpression,"-")` to clean up existing usernames.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "User name:")]
[StringLength(256, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 7)]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "The user name can only contain letters and numbers.")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need a way to check to see if a username contains any special characters or white space, and if that username does remove the special characters and replace them with an under score _.

Comment: That's what you *need* - what is your actual, specific question?

Comment: And by what definition do you consider some characters to be "special"?

Comment: Two links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx and http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Oh wow I did not think I would have to expand so much on this question. Let me try to do better by adding a little more info to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

If by "special" you mean single quote and exclamation mark (just as an example), then the regular expression `[ '!]` will match a single character which is space, quote, or exclam.

Answer (score 0):

"\W" matches any character other than letters, numbers, and underscores.  You could do a global replacement of "\W" with "_" although it might be less surprising for your users if you just check for "\W" and then return an error message telling them which characters are and aren't allowed.